# Properly quoting a tcsh alias using backticks

Tags: linux, perl, alias, tcsh

I'm using tcsh. I'd like to alias "cdup" to `cd` up to a directory one level down from a reference directory. For example, if my reference directory is /home/myself/support/bugs/, and I'm in /home/myself/support/bugs/bug1/foo/bar, I'd like `cdup` to change directory to /home/myself/support/bugs/bug1.
I tried the following:

`` alias cdup 'cd `perl -e \'print $1 if $ENV{PWD} =~ m#\(/home/myself/support/bugs/[^/]+\)#\'`' ``

but I get:

Unmatched `.

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated compared to `cd ../..`?

Comment: that's not going to help if he is 5 directories down from his reference dir.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339328/creating-alias-for-cmd-with-backticks

Comment: The way the question is posed may contain a bug --- your alias will end up being `cd` if you are not within the reference directory, ie. it will put you in the home directory ... is that really what you want?  If so, the code can be simplified. If not, then what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of that quoting is unnecessary,<sup>†</sup> what makes this far easier

```
alias cdup cd `perl -e'print $1 if $ENV{PWD} =~ m{(/home/user/support/bugs/[^/]+)}'`
```

Or you can break up the job and avoid quoting issues

```
set d=`perl -e'print $1 if $ENV{PWD} =~ m{(...)}'`; alias cdup $d; unset d
```

These both do the same, in `tcsh`.

However, if `pwd` is not within that "*reference directory*" then the alias ends up being `cd`, what puts you back into the home directory. This is how the question is posed -- but is that really desired?

One way to remedy this in the first approach above is to set the directory to the current directory itself if we are outside of the reference hierarchy

```
alias cdup cd `perl -e'$ENV{PWD} =~ m{(...)}; print $1 // $ENV{PWD}'`
```

Here `//` is the [defined-or operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Logical-Defined-Or).

Or it may be more suitable to avoid setting the alias altogether when outside the reference hierarchy, but then that need be done in `tcsh`

```
set d=`perl -e'print $ENV{PWD} =~ m{(...)}'`; if ($d != "") alias cdup cd $d ; unset d
```

Because of the capturing `()` in regex the match operator in list context (imposed by `print`) returns its capture or `undef` (if it didn't match), so shell's variable `$d` ends up being either the captured value or an empty string.

Then the alias is set conditionally -- so *there is no `cdup`* if there was no match.

---

<sup>†</sup>  From [tcsh manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh)

> **alias** [*name* [*wordlist*]]
> Without arguments, prints all aliases. With *name*, prints the alias for *name*. With *name* and *wordlist*, assigns *wordlist* as the alias of *name*. *wordlist* is command and filename substituted. *name* may not be 'alias' or 'unalias'. See also the *unalias* builtin command.

Note no mention of quotes, which are not needed for the *wordlist*

Comment: @Ala_Poubelle Thank you for attribution. Note the edit -- I added a way to avoid setting an alias when outside of that "reference" hierarchy.  (So then `cdup` wouldn't at all exist as a command.) This may or may not be what you need of course -- I am just letting you know that there is that option as well now

Answer (score 2):

So according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339328/creating-alias-for-cmd-with-backticks (thanks brian d foy), the answer was:

`` alias cdup 'cd `perl -e '\''print $1 if $ENV{PWD} =~ m#(/home/wittmann/support/bugs/[^/]+)#'\''`' ``

This works perfectly. Thanks for the trick to use ''' to introduce a single quote (') inside a single quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant without external commands:

```
alias cdup cd /home/myself/support/bugs/\$PWD:s./home/myself/support/bugs/..:ah
```

It differs from the original behavior in that if used outside the *reference directory* tree, it changes to the *reference directory*, which may or may not be preferred.